# Query takes too much time to process

Tags: oracle, unix

I just need an approach for this question. Our application connects to Oracle database. It is running fine in production but occasionally some queries take too much time to process (like 5-7 seconds). Sometimes they are update queries and sometimes select queries.
I just want to know how to approach such issues, any tools like nmon would help. Thanks.

Comment: Indexes are not necessarily the answer. That is just a wild guess. You need to identify root cause of the problem before providing a solution.

Comment: AWR/ASH reports would help. google it. ADDM may help.

Answer (score 1):

90% or more of poor performing queries come down to the execution plan. And probably 90% of those are related to statistics. The place to start would be to get a SQL Monitor report, which will show you the execution plan, together with runtime statistics and identify where time is being spent. Only when you understand the problem, can you come up with the correct solution.
If you are not familiar with SQL Monitor, check out http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/manageability/sqlmonitor-084401.html